# Understanding JavaScript Object(value)

Tags: javascript

I understand that the following code wraps a number into an object:

```
var x = Object(5);
```

I therefore expect and understand the following:

```
alert(x == 5); //true
alert(x === 5); //false
```

However, I also understand that an object is a list of **key/value pairs**. So I would have expected the following to be different:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(5)); //5
alert(JSON.stringify(x)); //5
```

What does the structure of x look like? And why does it not appear to be in key/value pair format?

Comment: What's at issue here is the behavior of `JSON.stringify()`, is that right?

Comment: I was not sure. I guess I took the definition that all objects are key/value pairs too literally and as a result, expected something in a key/value pair format.

Comment: Well that's kind-of what I mean; the output from `JSON.stringify()` in your question is the result of how that particular API works. It explicitly understands that Number instances should be treated as numeric values in the resulting JSON.

Comment: Similarly, String instances are treated as if they were string primitives, and Boolean instances as boolean primitives.

Comment: But .... the object still has key/value pairs, the Number object has a `primitiveValue` property, where the value is `5`, it's just like Pointy explains, some API's understand the difference between a "regular" object, and an object just holding a primitive value.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [Object constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) creates an object wrapper for the given value, of a Type that corresponds to the value.

So you get a [Number object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) with the primitive value 5 when passing a number to `Object`

```
var x = Object(5);
```

it's exactly the same as doing

```
var x = new Number(5);
```

when calling [valueOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf) on both, you get the primitive value `5` back again, which is why stringifying it gives the same as stringifying the number `5`, the object is converted to it's primitive value before stringifying

The specification for `JSON.stringify` says

> Boolean, Number, and String objects are converted to the corresponding primitive values during stringification, in accord with the traditional conversion semantics.

Comment: So the following return false because it's a different instance?   var x = Object(5);
   var y = new Number(5);
   alert(x === y);

Comment: @Sandy - yes, when comparing directly and strict, it's still objects, and two objects are never the same

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = Object(5);
```

This boxes 5 as an object, so Stringify just unboxes the value.

If you assign a key/value to an object, Stringify will display as such :

```
var x = {};
x.foo = "bar";
```

This is javascript Duck Typing - basically *if it looks like a duck, and sounds like a duck, it must be a duck* however replace duck with a data type, such as int or collection... https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing

Answer (score 0):

In a javascript console, I entered the following:

```
> var x = Object(5);
> x
[Number: 5]
> JSON.stringify(5)
'5'
> JSON.stringify(x)
'5'
```

When you use `Object(5)`, you are creating an object with key/value pairs. However, `JSON.stringify()` is turning that object into it's string representation -- "5". Calling `JSON.stringify()` on a literal value like the primitive number 5 also returns it's string representation -- "5". You're converting both the object and the primitive to strings, that's why they are equal.